# Replacement PDFTK with ghostscript

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript, pdftk

We've just moved hosting to a new server and hosting company. After the moved we've noticed there's a function we've missed during testing. The function creates PDFs with pdftk:

```
exec('pdftk mypdf.pdf fill_form mydata.fdf output myoutput.pdf flatten', $output);
```

Problem is, there's no pdftk on the new server and we also couldn't get it. Only three PDF related tools are available.

1. PDF-Tools
2. HTMLDoc
3. Ghostscript

PDF-Tools and HTMLDoc doesn't work due to a lack of functions.

Is there a way to replace the command line we have at the moment we ghostscript or is there maybe a PHP Library i haven't found yet?

Comment: Without knowing what your command line does, I can't tell you if you can use Ghostscrit. However, at a guess, you're filling in the fields of a PDF form with data from another file. No, you can't do that with Ghostscript from the command line. You could write a PostScript program to do it, but that would be difficult.

Comment: Correct. PDF Form gets filled by a data file and then I flat the output file.

Comment: Ghostscript doesn't have any means for filling a PDF form. As I said, you could write a PostScript program to read the external file and have that drive Ghostscript to do what you want, but there is no solution already available using Ghostscript.